# New Build, asrock h87,-itx no video output

Tags: troubleshooting, computer-building

Im building a system with a asrock h87m-itx, 8gb gskill ddr3 1600, and a intel g3220 lga 1150

i put it together and it powers up but there is no video output. I tried hdmi and dvi.

ive also checked to make sure the power cables are pushed in tight on the motherboard.

what else can i do to troubleshoot this issue?

Addition: I have the speaker but i dont know where on the motherboard is the place to put the speaker

Comment: What is the power supply make/model? Are all parts new? Is the 4-pin power connector on the motherboard (near the CPU) connected, as well as the 24-pin? Is the CPU fan plugged into the CPU_FAN connector? Can you put a (clear) pic of your setup on imgur and link to it? If your case came with an onboard speaker, plug that it so you can hear any error beeps while the machine is booting.

Comment: the PSU is a corsair cx500. the 4pin power is plugged in on the mobo and the 24pin, the cpu fan is plugged in to the connector. i'll take a picture to show the setup. The system is a mix of old and new, all of the old parts were working. The only new parts are the cpu and the mobo. I have an onboard speaker but I do not know where to plug it in on the motherboard.

Comment: Hmm...yeah, the board doesn't seem to have an internal speaker connector. :(

Comment: I take it you don't get any video at all -- not even the post screen? Do the fans spin up? Has the motherboard been mounted on the risers (no chance of shorting against the case?). Is RAM seated properly (firmly clicked in place)? Unplug all USB/SATA/PCIe devices (if there are any) and see if you can get to post.

Comment: yeah no video at all, just a black screen. the psu fan spins up, the cpu fan does a staggered spin up im not sure if its supposed to do that. the motherboard is on the risers and i took the ram out and put it back to make sure its in good. right now the only thing plugged in is the cpu power, 24pin, cpu fan, ram, and the power switch wires and i still get nothing

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to run out of suggestions. Maybe reset the CMOS (unplug PSU, pull motherboard battery out for a couple of minutes). That sometimes fixes things. Is the PSU new? Do you have an alternate power supply you could try? Starting to think one of the new parts may be DOA...

Comment: i'll try that. and yeah i thnk its one of the new parts, i was running the same system with another motherboard and cpu right up until the point that i switched them out. thanks for the help

Comment: figured out that the motherboard is bad after testing with another motherboard.